# The Zip PHP extension is now required by Moodle

Tags: zip, server, moodle

i need help.i got this error The Zip PHP extension is now required by Moodle, info-ZIP binaries or PclZip library are not used anymore. while installing moodle on my server.
i enabled extension zip in configuration php but no result.!!!

Help Please!

Comment: Try phpinfo() to check if this module exists in your configuration and work in proper way.

Comment: thanks for replying .yes the module exist

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu 16.04 php7 Moodle 3.0 installation

apt-get install php-zip

:/usr/bin# ./php-config --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs --enable-mbstring --with mysql=/usr --with-pear --enable-sockets --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir=/usr --with-ttf --with-freetype-dir=/usr --with-zlib-dir=/usr --with-iconv --with-curl --with-openssl --with-mysqli --enable-soap --with-xmlrpc --enable-zip

service apache2 restart

**Notes:**
(:/usr/bin# ./php-config --enable-zip might have been enough, but I ran the whole command, just in case.)
Do not add the extension in the php.ini file. The installation automatically creates a 20-zip.ini file in /etc/php/7.0/apahce2/conf.d folder with the extension enabled

Answer (score 0):

Found some instructions here - https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/admin/environment/php_extension/zip

This is a copy of the above :

The native PHP zip extension is required to let Moodle 2 read or write ZIP compressed archives.

Native installations of php will need php zip library enabling by adding the line

```
extension=zip.so
```

to `php.ini`

However if your php was not compiled with the extension then...

Installation on Linux Systems

If your distribution doesn't include this extension by default, then you need to compile PHP yourself and include --enable-zip.

This general PHP configuration will work well with Moodle 2.0:

```
./configure  --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs --enable-mbstring --with mysql=/usr --with-pear --enable-sockets --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir=/usr --with-ttf --with-freetype-dir=/usr --with-zlib-dir=/usr --with-iconv --with-curl --with-openssl --with-mysqli --enable-soap --with-xmlrpc --enable-zip
```

Installation on Windows Systems

Uncomment this line in your php.ini:

```
extension=php_zip.dll
```

Note: The Zip extension is built-in since PHP 5.3.x on Windows. The above php.ini line and the corresponding dll file is not required if using the distribution from windows.php.net. Not verified on other distributions on other OSs.

Comment: Thank you sir.But this is not working for me i think i will try an old version of moodle .i can t figure out the solution .

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use:

```
sudo apt-get install php-zip
```

Then you must restart Apache Service, Use:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```